# OpenCV: "Feature Matching with FLANN" tutorial - getting exception

Tags: c++, opencv

I am starting up with OpenCV (using C++) and was playing around with the "Feature matching with FLANN" tutorial from here:
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html

I did not modify anything, just tried running it as it is. Unfortunately, when running it, I am getting this error when the program tries to detect the keypoints (on the line **detector.detect(img_1, keypoints_1)**) :

[image]

I had no problems with running other OpenCV tutorials out of the box...did anyone experience similar problems?

My system: Visual Express 2010 and OpenCV 2.3, under Windows 7 64-bit. Could this be a bug of v2.3, or some issues related to the 64-bitness of my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure helps to know more about C++ than a worm :) I realized I had linked against the release version of the feature2d lib. As always, solved automatically by virtue of the "power of posting"...

Answer (score 1):

I have same mistake with your‘s，because you have use different Version of lib file.
If you use debug,you must use lib ended by 'd'.